# BeautifulSoup scraping information from multiple divs using loops into JSON

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am scraping titles, descriptions, links, and people's names from a multiple divs that follow the same structure. I am using BeautifulSoup, and I am able to scrape everything out of the first div. However, I'm having trouble scraping from  my long list of divs, and getting the data in a portable format like CSV or JSON.

How can I scrape each item from my long list of divs, and store that information in JSON objects together for each mp3?

The divs look like this:

```
<div class="audioBoxWrap clearBoth">
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
    <p>Description 1</p>
    <div class="info" style="line-height: 1px; height: 1px; font-size: 1px;"></div>
    <div class="audioBox" style="display: none;">
        stuff
    </div>
    <div> [ <a href="link1.mp3">Right-click to download</a>] </div>
</div>
<div class="audioBoxWrap clearBoth">
    <h3>Title 2</h3>
    <p>Description 2</p>
    <div class="info" style="line-height: 1px; height: 1px; font-size: 1px;"></div>
    <div class="audioBox" style="display: none;">
        stuff
    </div>
    <div> [ <a href="link2.mp3">Right-click to download</a>] </div>
</div>
```

I've figured out how to scrape from the first div, but I cannot grab the info for each div. For example, my code below only spits out the h3 for the first div over and over.

I know that I can create a python list for titles, descriptions, etc, but how do I keep the metadata structure like JSON, so that title1, link1, and description1 stay together, as well as title2's information.

```
with open ('soup.html', 'r') as myfile:
    html_doc = myfile.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

    audio_div = soup.find_all('div', {'class':"audioBoxWrap clearBoth"})

    print len(audio_div)
    #create dictionary for storing scraped data. I don't know how to store the values for each mp3 separately.

    for i in audio_div:
        print soup.find('h3').text
```

I want my JSON to look something like this:

```
{  
   "podcasts":[  
      {  
         "title":"title1",
         "description":"description1",
         "link":"link1"
      },
      {  
         "title":"title2",
         "description":"description2",
         "link":"link2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over every track and make context specific searches:

```
from pprint import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <div class="audioBoxWrap clearBoth">
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>Description 1</p>
        <div class="info" style="line-height: 1px; height: 1px; font-size: 1px;"></div>
        <div class="audioBox" style="display: none;">
            stuff
        </div>
        <div> [ <a href="link1.mp3">Right-click to download</a>] </div>
    </div>
    <div class="audioBoxWrap clearBoth">
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <p>Description 2</p>
        <div class="info" style="line-height: 1px; height: 1px; font-size: 1px;"></div>
        <div class="audioBox" style="display: none;">
            stuff
        </div>
        <div> [ <a href="link2.mp3">Right-click to download</a>] </div>
    </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

tracks = soup.find_all('div', {'class':"audioBoxWrap clearBoth"})
result = {
    "podcasts": [
        {
            "title": track.h3.get_text(strip=True),
            "description": track.p.get_text(strip=True),
            "link": track.a["href"]
        }
        for track in tracks
    ]
}
pprint(result)
```

Prints:

```
{'podcasts': [{'description': 'Description 1',
               'link': 'link1.mp3',
               'title': 'Title 1'},
              {'description': 'Description 2',
               'link': 'link2.mp3',
               'title': 'Title 2'}]}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Except why does the result have description, link, and title in a different order from what you have in result=?  Also, my printed descriptions take up many lines in the terminal (descriptions are actually whole paragraphs). Is that just a feature of pprint, and not the actual contents of the quotation marks in description?

Comment: @moglido sure, this is just a dictionary - it does not have a predefined order.